# Big O complexity of loop with two independent inner loops

Tags: language-agnostic, complexity-theory, big-o, time-complexity

I have a function that depends on three variables, `T`, `N`, and `M`. The loop is the following:

```
for each t from 0 to T {
    for each n from 0 to N {
         process(n,t);
    }
    for each m from 0 to M {
         process(m,t);
    }
}
```

What would be the big-O run-time complexity of this? I am thinking `O(T*Max(n,m))` but is this standard? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to analyze this is to look at the total amount of work being done across all iterations of the loop by determining how many times the outer loop executes and multiplying it by the amount of work done by the body of the loop.  To do this, we'll work inside-out.

Starting with the inside, note that the first loop runs O(N) times, and does some amount of work on each iteration (I'll assume that it's O(1) work, though this analysis can be modified in case that's not true).  Consequently, this loop does O(N) work.  The second loop, similarly, does O(M) work.  Thus the total amount of work done by the body of the loop is O(M + N).  Since the top-level loop runs O(T) times, each iteration doing O(M + N) work, the total amount of work done is O(T(M + N)) = O(TM + TN).

Your claim that this is equal to O(T max{M, N}) is also correct.  One way to see this is as follows: note that N = O(max{M, N}) and M = O(max{M, N}), and therefore we have that

> O(TM + TN)
>
> = O(T max{M, N} + T max{M, N})
>
> = O(2T max{M, N})
>
> = O(T max{M, N})

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is `N = O(max{M, N})` true?

Comment: @Inspired- Yes.  Let M and N vary.  At any point, if N >= M, then N <= N = max{M, N}.  If N < M, then N < M = max{M, N}.  Using the formal definition of big-O, pick n0 = 0, c = 1, and the above reasoning establishes the result.

Comment: @templatetypedef While this is perfectly true when applying the formal definition, here is a citation from wikipedia: "Informally, especially in computer science, the Big O notation often is permitted to be somewhat abused to describe an asymptotic tight bound". When we are speaking about algorithm's complexity in big-O notation, we are probably assuming big-Theta (otherwise `O(T^100*m^100*n^100)` would be also an appropriate answer). That's why `N = O(max{M,N})` is somewhat confusing to those who is used to abuse the Big O (like me :) ).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is correct. And it's the same as `O(T*(m+n))`. Which is "standard" - hard to tell, but `max` seems to be used more often.